# How to set up keyboard shortuts with custom modifiers (like Mod3) in Cinnamon?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, cinnamon

I'm trying to migrate from Mate into Cinnamon. In Mate, it was possible to assign custom modifiers to *Switch to workspace on the left of the current workspace*. In Cinnamon keyboard configuration applet, the "Mod3" modifier is ignored.

Is there any "backdoor" or command-line way for assigning keyboard assignments for switching workspaces that bypass the configuration applet?

Unfortunately I can't find these shortcuts with dconf-tool nor with gconf-editor.

There is also similar question on AskUbuntu: [How to change key bindings for switching workspaces in gnome3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171328/how-to-change-key-bindings-for-switching-workspaces-in-gnome3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I've found a solution.

It appears, that the setting is in `dconf-editor` after all. The problem was with very bad support for searching in this tool.

To edit workspace keyboard settings one should use dconf-tool and edit settings under path `org`->`gnome`->`desktop`->`wm`->`keybindings`.

The syntax is the same as in other Gnome editions.

You can use this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
gsettings set org.cinnamon.muffin.keybindings move-to-workspace-down "['<Shift><Mod3>Down']"
gsettings set org.cinnamon.muffin.keybindings move-to-workspace-left "['<Shift><Mod3>Left']"
gsettings set org.cinnamon.muffin.keybindings move-to-workspace-up "['<Shift><Mod3>Up']"
gsettings set org.cinnamon.muffin.keybindings move-to-workspace-right "['<Shift><Mod3>Right']"

gsettings set org.cinnamon.muffin.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down "['<Mod3>Down']"
gsettings set org.cinnamon.muffin.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left "['<Mod3>Left']"
gsettings set org.cinnamon.muffin.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up "['<Mod3>Up']"
gsettings set org.cinnamon.muffin.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right "['<Mod3>Right']"
```

Comment: The current group is `org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.wm`